Segmenting an arc
I am having difficulty knowing what side of a circle I am getting segments for.  Most of the time I need the red section of the circle.  This red section can be anywhere around the circle.  I can tell what side I need by comparing the distance for the center to the mid point to the arc height.  The code have have works most of the time but fails when the red section is at different locations around the circle.  I hope I have explained well enough for someone to give me some help.

    Dim ArcHeight As Double = xyz.GetArcHeight

    Direction = GetDirection222(lstxyz)
    Dim startAngle As Double = Math.Atan2(startY - centerY, startX - centerX)
    Dim endAngle As Double = Math.Atan2(endY - centerY, endX - centerX)
    If xyz.GetArcHeight < xyz.Radius Then
        If startAngle > endAngle Then
            endAngle += 2 * Math.PI
        End If
    Else
            Console.WriteLine("What To do?")
        If startAngle > endAngle Then
            endAngle += 2 * Math.PI
        End If
    End If



    Dim sweepAngle As Double = endAngle - startAngle

    ' Calculate the arc length
    Dim arcLength As Double = radius * sweepAngle

    ' Define the desired length of each segment as a fraction of the arc length
    Dim segmentLengthFraction As Double = 0.01 ' Adjust this value to control the segment length as a fraction of the arc length

    ' Calculate the number of segments based on the desired segment length
    Dim numSegments As Integer = _CirSegments 'CInt(Math.Ceiling(arcLength / (radius * segmentLengthFraction)))

    ' Calculate the angle increment for each segment
    Dim angleIncrement As Double = sweepAngle / numSegments

    ' Create GraphicsPath to hold line segments
    Dim path As New GraphicsPath()
    Dim segments As New minMax
    Dim lstsegments As New List(Of minMax)

    ' Add the first point of the arc to the path
    path.AddLine(CSng(startX), CSng(startY), CSng(centerX + radius * Math.Cos(startAngle)), CSng(centerY + radius * Math.Sin(startAngle)))


    ' Add line segments approximating the arc
    For i As Integer = 1 To numSegments
        Dim angle As Double = startAngle + i * angleIncrement
        Dim nextX As Double = centerX + radius * Math.Cos(angle)
        Dim nextY As Double = centerY + radius * Math.Sin(angle)

        segments = New minMax
        segments.minx = CSng(path.GetLastPoint().X)
        segments.miny = CSng(path.GetLastPoint().Y)
        segments.maxx = CSng(nextX)
        segments.maxy = CSng(nextY)
        lstsegments.Add(segments)
        path.AddLine(CSng(path.GetLastPoint().X), CSng(path.GetLastPoint().Y), CSng(nextX), CSng(nextY))
    Next

    Return lstsegments


You probably want atan2 to get an unambiguous angle but the question as posed is unanswerable. How can we possibly guess which part of your circle arc is red?

I do know the the start points and end points of the red arc.  I think the issues is with the angle being great than 90?

That is why you need atan2 - it accepts the two sides of the defining triangle and returns an angle in the range -pi to +pi in the appropriate quadrant.

That is what I am using to get the start and end angles.  Sorry the below lines are missing from the posted code.
Dim startAngle As Double = Math.Atan2(startY - centerY, startX - centerX)
Dim endAngle As Double = Math.Atan2(endY - centerY, endX - centerX)

You should edit the question so that it includes all the facts. Comments are ephemeral.

I updated the code in the original at same time I posted the comment.   Thank you for the help
